# Understanding of xor sum comparing with zero

Tags: c++, checksum, boolean-logic, xor, crc

I have some interesting code that approves recieved data(?). This code does something like:

```
// some recieved data const char data[n] 
unsigned char low = 0;
unsigned char high = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
low ^= data[i];
high ^= data[i+1];
} 

if(low != 0 || high != 0) {
// prints error
return;
}
```

Here I cannot understand meaning of this compare statements. It would be obvious if it compares with some value but not just zero. Why low and high must be equal to zero to continue working with recieved data. Sorry for too easy question but google and chat gpt didnt explain it to me clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without more context. Maybe, the last two bytes are some kind of check code so that they zero out the accumulated values if the data wasn't corrupted.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Kindly add more description about the specific problem you are trying to solve. Otherwise it would be difficult to answer.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the problem is. You are fine with some XOR chain that results in some specific value, but just not when that value is 0? Are you aware that `a ^ b == c` means that `(a ^ b) ^c == 0`? Or in other words, that any value XORed by itself is zero.

Comment: It must be like that because the sent data was constructed that way.

Comment: It looks like [Parity byte or parity word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum#Parity_byte_or_parity_word). (I knew that I've already seen something like that in the past...) ;-)

Comment: code as posted is undefined when data is `char [n]` due to going out of bounds.

Answer (score 4):

The `xor` of all bytes of a message can be used as checksum. It makes use of the fact that `a xor a == 0`. The sum is calculated by both sender and receiver. The sender adds their checksum to the message. If the receiver calculates the `xor` of **all** bytes (including the checksum) they should get a `0` or the message was corrupted.

Comment: Technically, the code xor's 16 bit words, not 8 bit bytes, and assumes that `n` is an even number.